# Image Upload in CakePHP on localhost

Tags: php, cakephp

i am getting an error in uploading image into folder. there is an error occured during uploading that image.
my Controller Code is (cakeplus is my root folder ex: htpp://localhost/cakeplus) :

```
$directory = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/cakeplus/pics';

                if(!is_dir($directory)) {
                    mkdir($directory,0777);
                }

                $files_array = $this->data['Photo']['path'];
                //pr($files_array); die;

                    if(isset($files_array['name']) && $files_array['name']!='') {
                        $filetype = $files_array['type'];
                        $filesize = $files_array['size'];
                        $filename = $files_array['name'];
                        $filetmpname = $files_array['tmp_name'];

                        $file_type          =   explode('.',$filename);
                        $ext_name           =   array_reverse($file_type);
                        $final_file_title   =   $ext_name[1];
                        $file_name          =   Inflector::slug( str_replace( ".".$ext_name[0], "" , $filename ).   '_' .time() ,'-' );
                        $newFileName        =   $file_name.'.'.$ext_name[0];
                        move_uploaded_file($filetmpname, $directory.'/'.$newFileName);      

                        $requirementuploadData['Photo']['path'] = $file_name;

                        $this->Photo->create();
                        $this->Photo->save($requirementuploadData,false);


                    }
```

Error(s)(Warnings) :

```
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/cakeplus/pics/wallpaper-1433586197.png): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections [APP\Controller\PhotosController.php, line 31]
    Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpA80D.tmp' to 'http://localhost/cakeplus/pics/wallpaper-1433586197.png' [APP\Controller\Photos
```

Comment: Like the error says, you can't write to an HTTP stream. You need to write the file to the file system, or use some other method to move it elsewhere if that's what you need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the CakePHP [Upload plugin](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload) - it will abstract away much of the work that goes into dealing with file and image uploads.

The error you are seeing is because you cannot use `move_uploaded_file()` to transfer from a file path (`C:\xampp\tmp\phpA80D.tmp`) to an HTTP URL (`http://localhost/cakeplus/pics/wallpaper-1433586197.png`).

If you don't want to use the Upload plugin, and would prefer to keep working with what you already have, I would start by changing the `$directory` path. Something like this might be more appropriate:

```
$directory = WWW_ROOT . 'pics';
```

This will contain the path to your `./yourapp/webroot/pics` directory, which is also the location of `http://yourapp.com/pics`.

Check out the documentation for more [predefined paths](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#core-definition-constants).

Answer (score 0):

may be folder dont have permission to write an image.
you should to use cakephp upload component.

```
$this->Upload->upload($file,$destination,$name);
```

Comment: dont need to use "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in $directory just use folder path.